# pod spec lint: not logging errors in the terminal

Tags: objective-c, cocoapods

when I run  pod spec lint  in terminal it is showing the following error but it is not logging the errors
[!] The spec did not pass validation, due to 4 errors.

So I am unable to determine where the errors are occurring.

Comment: It really should be logging them but I have the same issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While `pod spec lint` should output errors regardless, you can run `pod spec lint --verbose` to see a lot more output.

Comment: Thank you I am able to see the errors and fixed them.